# Serveral phones with same AppStore/Google login

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I a have a large cluster of phones, about 100, in several places in the world. They are wall mounted, and I cannot access them physically, they all must be in silence (so are configured to reject calls, and be in silence). I have remote team viewer installed and setup to remotely access them.

All of those devices are logged in, as the same user in Android/PlayStore.

What I see, is that once in a while, the user gets logged out. I am unsure why the user gets logged out. This is first issue.

Second issue, is that when I do login, all other phones will get prompted to accept the login. This makes noise, and the phones should be in complete silence. How can I prevent the "Is this you?" popup to be displayed on all devices? (lets say I do have a few backups for me to accept it).

EDIT:

As suggested:
I viewed:
https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup/1 (79 devices - ok)
https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity - all devices seen
In my shared GMail account - I don't see anything.

I am open for more ideas.

Comment: As to the auto-logouts - I can't tell you what causes it, but I can say that I've seen it once in a while on my own phone, so I don't think it's anything specific to your setup.

Comment: @MichaelKohne that is not good news. This renders Android as non-usable for unattended setups like mine.

Comment: possibly, though it's entirely possible that you could find out what's going on and solve it. I'd start by looking at the recent security events on your google account immediately after a disconnect event and see if that has any clues.

Comment: "This renders Android as non-usable for unattended setups like mine." Only if you need to use Playstore/GApps. You can use Android without that, you know? ;)

Comment: @Izzy and how do I do unattended upgrades? Are you telling me to reflush the system image with a custom ROM, which has my app as system app, so I can gain PACKAGE_INSTALL permissions ? (rhetorical question of course).

Comment: That all depends very much upon your requirements. If you rely on apps via Playstore, I don't see a way out. But there are certainly "unattended setups" that can do without. And yes, a custom ROM with F-Droid and its privileged extension would be one way to achieve that. You could even add your own custom repo and feed it with the apps you need from other sources. Just an idea, not sure if that fits your setup.